# I have created a wordpress web site but after some time it blocks from google and all the folders in my cpanel contains .htaccess files

Tags: wordpress, blocked

I have created a wordpress web site but after some time it blocks from google and all the folders in my cpanel contains .htaccess files.and i have to reinstall the wordpress but i have to delete all the files one by one in each folder is there any issue in theme or any attacker wants to hack the site.

i need a simple solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
WordPress comes with a built-in feature that allows you to instruct search engines not to index your site. All you need to do is visit Settings » Reading and checked if  the box next to Search Engine Visibility option is check so need to unchecked.
[image]

**Solution 2:**
Check the robots.txt file on your root folder and remove the

" Disallow: / "

inside the file.
Try both solutions and let me know if you have any question.
Thanks.